# Updating a lightning node to latest version

Tags: raspberry-pi, lightning-network-daemon

I'm running a lightning node on a Raspberry Pi. I'm still learning about the technology and linux as well. But I'm not sure how to securely update my node to the new LND version 0.4.1 and I'd like some directions.

I already downloaded LND binaries and checked the keys.

```
$ wget https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/releases/download/v0.4.1-beta/lnd-linux-arm-v0.4.1-beta.tar.gz
```

I used this to install the previous version (0.4-beta)

```
$ tar -xzf lnd-linux-arm-v0.4-beta.tar.gz
$ ls -la
$ sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin lnd-linux-arm-v0.4-beta/*
```

But how should I proceed if I just want to update, considering I'm not installing from scratch? What commands should I use? Should I backup anything before doing this (like channeldb.db)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic update procedure from v0.4.0 to v0.4.1:

- stop LND
- delete macaroon files in LND directory (to prevent [this issue](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/921))
- install new version exactly like before (as documented above)
- start LND
- unlock wallet with `lncli unlock` to create new macaroon files

In case you are following my [RaspiBolt guide](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/README.md), you might want to copy the macaroon file to the admin home directory again: `sudo cp /home/bitcoin/.lnd/admin.macaroon /home/admin/.lnd/` (see more details [here](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/issues/57))